# How to ensure that password is entered?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to get password from user.

If he simply enter nothing [just press the enter key alone], then warning should be thrown.

```
$NewUserPassword = Read-Host -assecurestring "Please enter New Run time user password"

$NewUserPassword=$NewUserPassword.Trim()
If ( ($NewUserPassword -eq $null) -or ($NewUserPassword -eq "") ){

    Write-Warning "Please enter valid password. Script execution is stopped"
    Exit
}
```

But script throws error as follows

> Method invocation failed because [System.Security.SecureString]
>   doesn't contain a method named 'Trim'.

But if i remove trim() method ,the application still doesn't throw warning.

What could be the reason? How to get valid password?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot inspect the value of a SecureString instance directly and comparing with a `String` instance is futile anyway. However, it has a `Length` property which you can use for checking whether it is empty:

```
$NewUserPassword = Read-Host -assecurestring "Please enter New Run time user password"
If ($NewUserPassword.Length -eq 0){
    Write-Warning "Please enter valid password. Script execution is stopped"
    Exit
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If you convert the `SecureString` to a `String` you can use the `trim()` member function on this object. This might also be handy if you want to perform other checks (password complexity ...)

   ```
   $NewUserPassword = ([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($NewUserPassword))).trim()
   ```
2. Alternatively you could use `length` property of the `SecureString` object. **Important:** Passwords containing only spaces, will have a length greater than 0.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using Get-Credential ?
You can store passwords, save them to a file and use that later

$password = Get-Credential
$password.Password